# Is it possible to verify google analytics code, crazzy egg code, Optimizely code by selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am a new tester in selenium IDE.
I can check meta content by selenium IDE. But, I need to check some scripts as like Google analytics, crazy egg etc.

Is selenium ide have any opportunity to check script automatically?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?
Selenium is for GUI tests. But in fact you can get HTML attribute values or the value between HTML tags. My opinion is, test whole scripts with Selenium seems a bad idea.

Comment: IDE is very limited - can replay past GUI interactions, that's all. Selenium scripting using any of supported programming languages (Python, Java, ...) and Webdriver has much more powers (and with more powers goes more responsibility, but you already know that).

Answer (score 1):

By IDE you can't check the code (scripts), but you can check the results of running code (scripts) - the HTML tags or their changes.
More variability to Selenium IDE you can add with Selblocks plugin, which allows you to make conditions and jumps.